# How access to Nested Arrays: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, instagram

I am currently working on a project where a user's followers are given to me in an array that looks like the one here: http://pastebin.com/304iPm4L

Array:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (3) { 
["pagination"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) 
    { 
    ["next_url"]=> string(146) "DATA"
    ["next_cursor"]=> string(13) "DATA" 
    } 
["meta"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) 
    { 
    ["code"]=> int(200) 
    } 
["data"]=> array(9) 
    { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (4) 
        { 
        ["username"]=> string(7) "twurked" 
        ["profile_picture"]=> string(106) "https://igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-19/11055444_697242820403478_108851570_a.jpg" 
        ["id"]=> string(9) "307611076" 
        ["full_name"]=> string(20) "#twurked For Reposts" 
        } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#6 (4) 
        {
         ["username"]=> string(12) "itsmarziapie" 
        ["profile_picture"]=> string(107) "https://igcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t51.2885-19/10735354_634448103338889_1219780551_a.jpg" 
        ["id"]=> string(9) "415505158" 
        ["full_name"]=> string(15) "Marzia Bisognin" 
        } 
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#7 (4) 
        { 
        ["username"]=> string(11) "briankgrubb" 
        ["profile_picture"]=> string(107) "https://igcdn-photos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t51.2885-19/10518270_1508565329429347_713909002_a.jpg" 
        ["id"]=> string(8) "28307611" 
        ["full_name"]=> string(11) "Brian Grubb" 
        } 
    [3]=> object(stdClass)#8 (4) 
        { 
        ["username"]=> string(16) "redbulladventure" 
        ["profile_picture"]=> string(106) "https://igcdn-photos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-19/11007825_728249480627075_348216069_a.jpg" 
        ["id"]=> string(10) "1721797894" 
        ["full_name"]=> string(18) "Red Bull Adventure" 
        } 
     } 
}
```

What I am trying to do is take the `username` value of each of those users and output it to the screen.

So, what I came up with was that I could easily (or so I thought...) loop through my results and output just the `username` value in each nested array.

I used this code:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
    $instagram->getUserFollows('self',10)->data[$i]["username"]; 
    echo "<br/>";
    $i++;
}
```

The `$instagram->getUserFollows('self',10)` array, is what you saw in pastebin. By looking at my nested arrays, it seemed like I needed a number, and then `["username"]` in order to access each username.

In theory, `$instagram->getUserFollows('self',10)->data["1"]["username"];` should output `itsmarziapie`

However, when I ran the above code, I got this:

`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

What does this error mean, and why can I not loop out my `username` data to the screen??

At this point, I have been troubleshooting for about 2.5 hours and now am looking to you guys for guidance. I know there are a lot of questions out there about the same error, but none of them included nested arrays like this one does, so I was a little lost.

Thanks for helping to point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Sorry for being obvious, but it means exactly what it states: you cannot use an object of type `stdClass` as array. Use `var_dump()` to check the **actual** contents of your variables.

Comment: @zerkms I realize that, but to me the solution to the error was very confusing. I had no idea how to access the array data within nested arrays. I understood the problem, but not well enough to find a solution on my own.

Comment: Well, if you used `var_dump` you would know they are not *nested arrays*. But guessing is funnier indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
//You request 10 objects but you don't know if there are really 10
    $info = $instagram->getUserFollows('self',10);

//How many objects?
    $qty = count($info->data);

/* You can't assume that there are 10 objects (I refer to your code, 
 * you have 9 objects and you try to access to 10 objects)    
 */
    for($i = 0; $i < $qty ; $i++) { 
      echo $info->data[$i]->username . "<br>";
    }
```